# Calibrate LCD display in laptop?

Tags: display-settings, crunchbang, ati

I installed Crunchbang Linux. I successfully installed the ATI drivers, and all works well. Except that the colors are bit weird. Hard to say what *exactly* is wrong, it is the notion that on another laptop (or windows on the same laptop) everything looks *better*. It's probably some combination of brightness/contrast/gamma settings.

Is there any comfortable way to adjust the display settings under Crunchbang, or Linux in general? Some nice calibration tool? I don't need a photography-quality display.

I used `aticonfig` to djust brigtness and contrast, and `xgamma` for gamma. but they are not very handy.

Comment: This question interests me greatly, but I am a bit doubtful that you'll receive a proper answer. On a MacBook, I've noticed that images in Safari are noticeably more vivid than those in Firefox. I mention this anecdotally because so many things are at play when you start to assess display quality that it's hard to assess which layer is the culprit.

Comment: The point is that I don't even know if bright./contr./gamma are sufficient to make the colors vivid and nice looking, or if there is some other "magic knob" somewhere there that I am not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Monica](http://freecode.com/projects/monica) - it's a handy GUI frontend that let's you calibrate your monitor. Monica depends on `fltk-devel` AFAIK. Read the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_color_management) on color management under Linux.

A little bonus (and one of my favourite monitor tools) is [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) which is the Linux equivalent of [F.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/). It sets the temperature of your monitor according to the position of the sun, so that your eyes will be more confortable staring at your screen at late hours.

Comment: I used *Redshift* and it works well. *Monica* gave strange results

Answer (score 0):

There is a gamma calibration tool in the gnustep packages (at least in Debian). You may want to give it a try. IIRC, it allowed adjustment of the channels independently.